# NAT-T set up using 3 linux machines

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ip, nat

I am trying to have a simple NAT-T setup using 3 linux machines.

```
Linux1                        Linux2(NATdevice)                       Linux3
(eth0) 192.168.1.51 <--->(eth1)192.168.1.80 & (eth0)192.168.2.203<-->192.168.2.77
```

I also set up ip forwarding enabled on Linux 2 machine which is supposed to act as a NAT-T device.

```
 sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

 sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
 sudo /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o -eth1 -m state --state         RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
 sudo /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

The Linux 1 has it default GW as 192.168.1.80 and Linux 3 as 192.168.2.203

I can `ping 192.168.1.51` from Linux 2. But i cannot `ping 192.168.2.77` from Linux 1.
On `wireshark` I see DHCP discover messages when I `ping 192.168.2.77` from `192.168.1.51`.

Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: seems like the subnetmask was to blame on linux1